# How can I disable DHTML menu on one of my drupal menus?

Tags: drupal, dhtml

I am new to drupal so forgive me. I made a menu and it was automatically created as a DHTML menu. I wanted to style the menu myself and just simply want the 'ul.menu' tree to be printed. Instead, it's doing some javascript and unnecessary CSS. can i disable DHTML menu for this particular menu?

thanks!

Comment: Are you using the DHTML Menu plugin? Which version? Which version of Drupal?

Answer (score 1):

**If** you are using DHTML Menus module, and are asking how to disable it for certain menus, then it should be possible via the configuration in Administrator > Site Configuration > DHTML Menus (as suggested by [this](http://drupal.org/node/345544) and [this](http://drupal.org/node/332947) discussion). Looks like they had this feature in v2.2, then lost after switch to 3.x, and re-included around 3.2 or so.

But you didn't specify whether you use this module or not, so my answer may be completely off due to lack of information.